# how to make it work automatically in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Do you know how to work backgroundworker with this code?

The request would be as I pulled out of google with a background worker and if so it is possible  to collect links from google pagination.

Not in label or how I'm new for that.
I just want To make go to next page like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and so on clicking button and make it go itself and pick up links through all pages with background worker or timer or how to make it work automatically as i said i'm new.
Like google has pagination.
It only goes through one page and stop on first number and do not move
far.

Thank you.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
         If (WebBrowser1.ReadyState WebBrowserReadyState.Complete =) Then
             For Each ClientControl I HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
                 IF NOT ClientControl.GetAttribute ("href"). Contains (Google) And ClientControl.GetAttribute ("href"). Contains ("http") and ClientControl.GetAttribute ("href"). Contains ("http") Then
                     ListBox1.Items.Add (ClientControl.GetAttribute ('href'))
                 end If
             Next
         end If

   end Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         WebBrowser1.Navigate (http://www.google.lt/search?num=100&q = "& ComboBox1.Text)
         BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync ()
     end Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
         For i = 0 to 100
             Threading.Thread.Sleep (200)
             BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress (i)
         Next

     end Sub

     Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
         Label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage
     end Sub
```

If do not understand what i mean to say so here is the example of that i want to get.
http://s2.postimage.org/a82mtrifh/i_need_this_to_go_far_through_all_pages_automati.png

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the Google URL you will see that there is a `start=` query

You can go straight to the page you want by modifying this: (Assuming 10 results per page)

Page 1

```
http://www.google.co.uk/#q=vb.net+book&start=0
```

Page 2

```
http://www.google.co.uk/#q=vb.net+book&start=10
```

Page 3

```
http://www.google.co.uk/#q=vb.net+book&start=20
```

Comment: This is the same as i click on each pages manully and not working at all.
Any help would be great but not this:(